# TS2339: Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to call the quantity variant from my redux files with this

```
const quantity = useSelector(state=>state.quantity)
```

but I get this error TS2339:

My redux files are these

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name:"cart",
    initialState:{
        products: [],
        quantity:0,
        total:0,
    },
    reducers:{
        addProduct:(state,action)=>{
            state.quantity +=1;
            state.products.push(action.payload.product);
            state.total += action.payload.price;
        },
    }
});

export const{addProduct} = cartSlice.actions
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

and this

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import cartReducer from "./cartRedux"

export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        cart:cartReducer,
    }
})
```

Comment: What does it display when you `console.log(state)` from the `useSelector` ?

Comment: The app wont even compile because of this error

Comment: if you change `const quantity = useSelector(state=>state.quantity)` to `const test = useSelector(state=>state)` does it run ?

Comment: Yes, it runs normally

Comment: Now console the `test` variable and share what it displays

Comment: it display these two new logs https://imgur.com/a/o8It66t

Comment: It looks like my "export default cartSlice.reducer;" need to be exported as an any type but I dont know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Add in your component file this (above your component right after imports or in the store file and export it):

```
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

and then use it like this:

```
const quantity = useSelector((state: RootState)=>state.quantity)
```